# Struggling to Decode Raw Hex Data of a Block

Tags: block, python

I am trying to Decode the Raw hex data of a Coinbase Block to check my understanding of the DS but I am facing some difficulties in decoding marked by a **?** below:

Q1. Can someone please check the existing understanding/interpratation and help explain and fill the gaps (marked by **?**)

Q2. Is there a simple standalone program/library in to do the same? I have seen few parsers (though haven't used) but they require the complete blockchain .dat files that i cannot afford to download for this task.

The block is: https://www.blockchain.com/btc/block/485300

```
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

[PARAMETER]           [VALUE]

[Block Header]
version             - 00000020
Previous Block hash - 53f7ebc735f54ac8d4ebcc1eeb3d3bdea89603bdd27431000000000000000000
Merkel Root         - ff964ec70ea5a5356a04fdb044ca6c59ffda2dd6be02c63d9ea58fb6d46e0199
time                - 1a22bb59
bits                - 1801310B
nonce               - f6df26f8

01 - transaction count

[Tx List]
version                 - 01000000
<?>                     - 0001
input ct                - 01
prev tx                 - 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
prev out n              - ffffffff
coinbase script length  - 31
coinbase script         - 03b46707244d696e656420627920416e74506f6f6c6b2f4542312f4144362f4e59412f332059bb221ab8080000615c0300
sequence                - ffffffff
Output count            - 02
value 1                 - 807c814a00000000
Script 1 length         - 19
Script 1                - 76a914660371326d3a2e064c278b20107a65dad847e8a988ac
value 2                 - 0000000000000000
Script 2 length         - 26
Script 2                - 6a24aa21a9ede2f61c3f71d1defd3fa999dfa36953755c690689799962b48bebd836974e8cf9
<?>                     - 0120
witness transaction id  - 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Comment: Q1 [segregated witness aka segwit](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0141.mediawiki) Also to be clear multibyte numbers are little-endian, and you've swapped `bits` to big-endian but not the others.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 thank you. updated the structure above for the seg_wit transaction id. just 4 bytes above unclear. can you please clarify those also?

Answer (score 0):

This [website](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_documentation#tx) can answer your question.

Typically, the first question mark refers to `flag` and the second question mark refers to `tx_witnesses`